# Android when system from screenoff to screenon the http(socket) also cannot be connect

Tags: android, sockets, http, service, sleep

The problem is purely on some models：
android4.4.4+

1. After the andorid system goes into hibernation, http can not connect to the server (in service [thread]), I have awakened the cpu (wifi state), but still does not work.

**update:**

> After about 10 minutes from the lock screen, the network connection is broken while (true) {http ==> connect server [thread sleep]}

```
//set wifi in BroadcastReceiver
 public static void setWifiDormancy(Context context){
    int value = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY,  Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_DEFAULT);
    Log.d(TAG, "setWifiDormancy() returned: " + value);
    final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("wifi_sleep_policy", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, value);

    editor.commit();

    if(Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER != value){
        Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);
    }
}
//wakeLock in service
public void wakeLockRequest(){
    if(wakeLock == null) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
    if(null != wakeLock && !wakeLock.isHeld()){
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }
}
//and in Service
startForeground(NOTIFYCATION_ID,createNotification());
```

2. After touching the lock screen, the app running in the background, and still can not connect to the server
3. When the user automatically click on the app, the network connection is restored (app in the foreground)

The first question, I have no way, at present can endure

The second problem I used a very stupid way to accept the screen on the broadcast, restart the app

I also try to restart the Service when screen on and screen off ,but The http is not work too.

Who has a good solution?Thanks!!!

Comment: When you awaken the cpu (wifi state) did you give it enough time for the wifi to connect?

Comment: @apmartin1991 I was receiving the lock screen broadcast, set to maintain wifi state, while the service is set to the foreground

Comment: Strange! When you do the network request, what is the error? Is there a data network present?

Comment: @apmartin1991 SocketTimeout exception,there is no data~